# Unable to send funds from GUI, error: Couldn't send the money: daemon is busy. Please try again later

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon

Dameon is connected and sync'd yet won't send funds. I've been trying for 2 days and every time it confirms the address and the send request and then after entering the wallet password it says "Couldn't send the money: daemon is busy. Please try again later."

Please help.

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

"Busy" means one of two things:

- the daemon has not finished syncing the blockchain
- the daemon has not found at least one other peer

Run "status" in monerod, and it'll tell you about both these things:

- The X/Y numbers at the start of the line tells you the height it's reached vs the height it thinks the network reached. It'll download and verify new blocks so X can increase to get to Y.
- The X(out)+Y(in) numbers near the end of the line tell you the number of peers you connected to and connected to you, respectively. If they're both zero, then your daemon is unable to connect to the Monero network.